# React State undefined after Set in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, state

This is Presentation file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class CreateZone extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
            this.state = {
                zone: {
                    name: '',
                    zipCodes: []
                }
            }
    }

    newZone(event){
        let newZone = Object.assign({}, this.state.zone)
        newZone[event.target.id] = event.target.value
        this.setState({
            zone: newZone
        })
    }
    submitZone(event){
        this.props.onCreate(this.state.zone)
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <input id="name" onChange={this.newZone.bind(this)} className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Zone Name" /><br />
            <input id="zipCodes" onChange={this.newZone.bind(this)} className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Zip Code" /><br />
            <button onClick={this.submitZone.bind(this)} className="btn btn-danger">Submit Comment</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default CreateZone
```

This is Container File:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Zone, CreateZone  } from '../presentation'
import { APImanager } from '../../utils'

class Zones extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            zone: {
                name: '',
                zipCodes: '',
                numComments: ''
            },
            list: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('componentDidMount')
        APImanager.get('/api/zone', null, (err, response) => {
            if(err){
                alert('Error in zones: '+err.message)
                return
            }

            this.setState({
                list: response.results
            })
        })
     }

    submitZone(zone){
        let newZone = Object.assign({}, zone)

        APImanager.post('/api/zone', newZone, (err, response) => {
            if(err) {
                alert('ERROR in New Zone: '+err.message)
                return
            }
            console.log('NewZone: '+JSON.stringify(response))
            let updatedList = Object.assign([], this.state.list)
            updatedList.push(response.result)
            this.setState({
                list: updatedList
            })


        })
    }

    render(){

        const listItems = this.state.list.map((zone, i) => {
            return (
                <li key={i}>
                    <Zone currentZone={zone} />
                </li>
            )
        })

        return(
            <div>
                <ol>
                    {listItems}
                </ol>
                <div>
                    <CreateZone onCreate={this.submitZone} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Zones
```

React doesn't re-render and console log error is "Cannot read property 'list' of undefined"
It worked fine before I moved form in to presentation file. This is training for me and I would love to understand what is going on

Answer (score 1):

The function submitZone in Zones Component is didn't get the "this" binded. So it was giving "this.state" as undefined. Bind the "this" same as

```
<button onClick={this.submitZone.bind(this)} className="btn btn-danger">Submit Comment</button>
```

So replace the line

```
<CreateZone onCreate={this.submitZone} />
```

with

```
<CreateZone onCreate={this.submitZone.bind(this)} />
```